# Get a multiple object back from req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http

Is it possible to get `req.body` back for more than single set of object?

HTML (EJS)

```
<form action="/newQuote" method="POST">
          <h4 id="new-form-heading">New Document</h4>

          <div class="total-quote-items">

            <div id="item1" class="quote-item">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Item</label>
                <a href="#" class="delete-item float-right text-danger" onclick="removeItem(this)"><i
                    class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                <input type="text" name="name1" class="form-control item-name" placeholder="List your item here !"
                  required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label>Quantity</label>
                  <input type="number" name="quantity1" class="form-control item-quantity" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label>Price</label>
                  <input type="number" name="price1" class="form-control item-price" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label>Total</label>
                  <input type="text" name="total1" class="form-control price-total" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <span class="btn btn-info add-item" onclick="addItem()"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> New Item</span>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary d-block" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
          </div>

        </form>
```

JS

```
function addItem() {

    numberofDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.quote-item').length + 1

    var original = document.querySelector('.quote-item')
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.querySelector('.item-name').value = '';
    // clone.querySelector('.item-name').name = '';

    clone.querySelector('.item-quantity').value = '';
    clone.querySelector('.item-quantity').name = '';

    clone.querySelector('.item-price').value = '';
    clone.querySelector('.item-price').name = '';

    clone.querySelector('.price-total').value = '';
    clone.querySelector('.price-total').name = '';

    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

    // console.log(numberofDiv)

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.quote-item')).forEach((itemId, i) => {
            console.log(itemId.querySelector('.item-name').name = 'name' + (i + 1))
            console.log(itemId.querySelector('.item-quantity').name = 'quantity' + (i + 1))
            console.log(itemId.querySelector('.item-price').name = 'price' + (i + 1))
            console.log(itemId.querySelector('.price-total').name = 'total' + (i + 1))

            // console.log(i)
            itemId.id = 'item' + ( i + 1 )
        })

}

function removeItem(param) {
    deleteItem = param.parentNode.parentNode

    numberofDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.quote-item').length - 1
    console.log(numberofDiv)

    if (numberofDiv <= 0) {
        return
    } else {
        deleteItem.remove()
    }

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.quote-item')).forEach((itemId, i) => {
        // console.log(itemId)
        // console.log(i)
        itemId.id = 'item' + ( i + 1 )
    })

}
```

App.js (route)

```
app.post('/newQuote', (req, res) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

        console.log(req.user.id)

        console.log(req.body)

    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }

});
```

This what I currently got back, as i add more than 1 item

```
{
  name1: 'apple',
  quantity1: '123',
  price1: '123',
  total1: '123',
  name2: 'banana',
  quantity2: '456',
  price2: '456',
  total2: '456',
  name3: 'carrot',
  quantity3: '789',
  price3: '789',
  total3: '789'
}
```

This is what how i would want it, (probably?)

```
{
      name1: 'apple',
      quantity1: '123',
      price1: '123',
      total1: '123',
},
{
      name2: 'banana',
      quantity2: '456',
      price2: '456',
      total2: '456',
},
{
      name3: 'carrot',
      quantity3: '789',
      price3: '789',
      total3: '789',
}
```

** Should i assign the iterate number for every item's name and other attributes?

** What i'm trying to achieve is `req.body` and for every input user have added, dynamically save the object(s) to MongoDB (If user add / post 4 quote items = 4 quote documents created and saved), I'm i on the right path here?

Comment: You should return an array of objects, with the same keys and then you can iterate over the array, the index would the the name{index}. Your authentication function should be a middleware. I don't understand how your code works really, but imo sending the response as an array of objects should do the job.

Comment: I also agree with @MFK34. Make the authentication a function or export it like so.  app.post('/newQuote', authenticationMiddleware, (req, res) => {   } and then in the route you can retrieve your form details with const { var1,var2,var3,ect } = req.body;

Comment: I would make an array of objects then stringy it in a event listener and sent it back as the data